# Should Validation communicate with database?

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi, fluentvalidation

I'm not sure if I'm using FluentValidation correctly. I'm confused.. should Validator communicate with the database?

For example, I have an endpoint to add `Item` to the `Order`. This is a model I'm working with and the corresponding validator:

```
public class ItemDto
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
}

public ItemValidator(IItemRepository itemRepository, IOrderRepository orderRepository)
{
    RuleFor(input => input.Price).GreaterThan(0);
    RuleFor(input => input.Quantity).GreaterThan(0);
    RuleFor(input => input.ItemId).Must(name => itemRepository.ItemExists(ItemId))
        .WithMessage(input => $"Item '{input.ItemId}' doesn't exists");
        .Must(name => itemRepository.ItemIsDiscontinued(ItemId))
        .WithMessage(input => $"Item '{input.ItemId}' is discontinued");
    RuleFor(input => input.OrderId).Must(name => orderRepository.OrderExists(OrderId))
        .WithMessage(input => $"Order '{input.OrderId}' doesn't exists");            
}
```

I was wondering, is this how the Validator should be used?

Alternative way is to check if particular order or item exists in the `Controller`, and return `NotFound()` if so. Then in the Validator I would check Price, Quantity and whether the item is discontinued?

I would love to have all the checks and validations in one place, but then if Item doesn't exist I would return 400 status error with the message "It doesn't exists" (aka. NotFound).

The question is, should I pus "exists validations" in the Controller and the rest in the Validator? If yes, where exactly is the line what shouldn't be in the validator?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

There is a limit to how many tests you can *reliably* do from mere Validation. The Database and only the Database has the final say on if the Input is valid.

Even if you could test theses things, by the time you **actually** input the Data into the Database the values might have changed. There is no reliable way to test it.

Stuff like the foreing key not being valid? That is a example for a [Exogenous Exception](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/). There is no way for you to avoid Exogenous Exceptions. You have to expect and handle them.

Comment: Thanks, just to clarify: What do you mean by "There is no reliable way to test it". You check if it exists in the DB, before you perform the insert. Also about exogenous exceptions, "You have to expect and handle them" - but where? In the Controller, Validator or let it go and wait to handle DB exception?

Comment: fyi. I'm catching and handling all DB exceptions already (so If such order of events happen: 1. Request came; 2. Check if exists and it doesl 3. Someone removes it; 4. Insert the record and the exception is thrown - I handle it). In the Validation I'm trying to avoid it.

Comment: @IshThomas: "You check if it exists in the DB, before you perform the insert" And between that test and the actuall Insert, the reality might have changed. A previously non-existent Key might have been added. A previously existing key might have been deleted. The Connection with the Database Could have been gone done. | You can not reliably test this.

Comment: Wait.. are you saying there should be NO db validation at all?

Comment: @IshThomas There is only one relevant validation. The one that happens *during* the INSERT. The one whose rules are maintained by the DBMS, based on the constraints and similar hints on the table. Everything before that? You can play with it for comformt. But propably just end up in a Race Condition with it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition

Comment: @IshThomas: It is very important to stress this. When working with a DB, the DB(MS) and **only** the DBMS is responsible for maintaining Data Integrity:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_integrity#Databases Nobody else is anywhere *close* to the position to do anything reliable in this area. Data Integrity is basically 1/2 to 3/4 of the job of a modern DBMS. Compared to that, giving Access to the Data is secondary.

Comment: Thanks, that I very interesting point of view. Didn't think that way tbh. I this case I would have to middleware "try and catch" that will return `BadRequest` on every exception. Is that what you would do?

Comment: @IshThomas There is a Second Article on Exception I link often, wich should help you with those qusetions: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET

Answer (score 0):

My vision:

1. You can use db related data in your validator
2. All db related validators should be transient or scoped. Use [HttpContextServiceProviderValidatorFactory](https://github.com/micro-elements/MicroElements.Swashbuckle.FluentValidation/blob/master/src/MicroElements.Swashbuckle.FluentValidation/HttpContextServiceProviderValidatorFactory.cs) for example
3. You can split validator to DB independent and DB dependent. Also you can use rules or include validators in one more global.

Risks:

- Your validation will fail without db
- You should mock repos for tests

Sample:
https://github.com/micro-elements/MicroElements.Swashbuckle.FluentValidation/blob/master/samples/SampleWebApi/Validators/BlogValidator.cs

Comment: "Your validation will fail without db" - I can create a BaseDbValidator class which will validate if the DB is available. Then every Validator which will have connection to the database will inherit from that Validator. As a result if you're sending request to the API, the API will tell you that DB is not available